# How to partially check object with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

is there a way how to partially match object with array property? Let's suppose that I'd like to test this object

```
    {
       "groups": [
          {
             "id": 1,
             "name": "Group 1",
             "people": [
                {
                   "firstName": "John",
                   "age": 23
                },
                {
                   "firstName": "Ethan",
                   "age": 18
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "id": 2,
             "name": "Group 2",
             "people": [
                {
                   "firstName": "Peter",
                   "age": 47
                },
                {
                   "firstName": "Henry",
                   "age": 55
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
```

and ensure that it contains group with name `Group 1` that contains `John` and `Ethan`.
I'm aware of jasmine.objectContaining but I don't know how to apply to this particular case.
Thank for any advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by using `jasmine.arrayContaining` and `jasmine.objectContaining` like below.

Please note: 'foo' is variable in which your test data resides as you wrote above.

```
describe("Array comparison", function () {

  it("matches objects with the expect key/value pairs", function() {

    expect(foo).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({

      groups: jasmine.arrayContaining([
        jasmine.objectContaining({name: "Group 2"}),
        jasmine.objectContaining({
            people: jasmine.arrayContaining([
              jasmine.objectContaining({firstName: "Peter"}),
              jasmine.objectContaining({firstName: "Henry"})
          ])
        })
       ])
    }));
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/upasanak/ed7osc7a/4/) is a jsFiddle for above working code.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this ? assume obj is ur object

```
var res = obj["groups"].find(function(a) { return a["name"] == "group 1"; });
res = res["people"].filter(function(person) {
         return ["Ethan","John"].includes(person["name"]); 
   });
```

now you can check `if ( res["people"].length == 2 )`

Comment: Thanks, however I prefer Upasana solution.